# Can I wipe EVERY records/traces wo/ factory reset on android?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, privacy, history

I' currently using LG V20 and an anciant Samsung YP-GP1.

I'm aware that IceCream Sandwitch doesn't have it's own built-in

encryption unlike modern devices, and want to keep

internal records/traces that stored inside the device's

memory deleted so my activity of the past would be remain secret even if

the device got lost/stolen without screen lock.

**To be specific, I want to delete records regarding external SDcard mount/unmount

activities, file copy/delete log if there's any.**

I know there's a Logcat, but is it really the only record that kept inside the device?